# subversion edge view vc output issue

Tags: svn, view, reverse-proxy, subversion-edge

I have installed subversion edge on a centos 6.4 virtual machine and setup a domain in host to do reverse proxy to it.

I could access the subversion edge. but when i browse the respository view integrated viewvc.. i get strange display of viewvc. can someone help why its so looks plain. something is missing in reverse proxy configuration that i am surely missing which unable to rendering CSS and images properly.

[image]

The output of above link when viewed inside virtual machine browsers is shown bellow.

[image]

My vhost_ssl.conf settings are:

```
SSLEngine On
SSLProxyEngine On
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
# Protect against BEAST exploit
SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCipherSuite RC4-SHA:HIGH

<Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>
KeepAlive On
KeepAliveTimeout 300
ProxyPass /svn/ https://172.16.150.18/svn/
ProxyPass /viewvc/ https://172.16.150.18/viewvc/
ProxyPass /csvn https://172.16.150.18:4434/csvn
SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1
SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
<Location /svn/>
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all      
</Location>

<Location /viewvc/>
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all      
</Location>

<Location /csvn>
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all      
</Location>
```

Comment: Found the cause. Actually looking at the view page source of viewvc page, i found that the css,js were pulled by /viewvc-static/xxx.css  . Hence, Seems like need to proxypass the root directory. i.e  ProxyPass / https:172.16.150.18/   now it worked. :-)  . i am glad that i found the solution myself.

Comment: You can add it as the answer below and accept it as the correct one.